# Redirecting calls in Twilio

Tags: twilio

I have an incoming call to my twilio number, i want to redirect that call to a different number but use the incoming calls number as caller id.

Is this possible without having to verify that phonenumber?

Comment: What you're asking would mean you would be able to send an incoming spam call to your phone number to another person without their permission?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior when an incoming call from the PSTN to Twilio, Twilio will pass-thru the CallerID when forwarding the call.

[Setting Up Call Forwarding](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding)

[callerId](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial)

> When you use  in your response to Twilio’s inbound call request,
> the dialed party sees the inbound caller's number as the caller ID.